# three.js replace fragment shader not working with release above 131

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I prepared an example of replacing standard material (fragment and vertex shader) [code sandbox r131.3](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pp-outlines-forked-8dev54?file=/src/shader/extendedShader.js:235-255) which was working well in three.js versions below **r131**. In releases above 131 changes applied to fragment shader stopped working (vertex works still as before).

Does anyone facing the same issue (any advice is warm welcome)?

Comment: Shader got changes since r131 and there is no that line `gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );` anymore. Thus, there is no replacing with your modificaitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option, use this modification (r144):

```js
    shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
      `#include <dithering_fragment>`,
      `#include <dithering_fragment>

        float t = time * 0.01 * 10.; // 10 variable speed
        float l = line(vPos, gridWidth, vec3(2.0));
        vec3 base = roadColor * wave(tuv.x, mix(0.5, roadCurve, getDelta(vPos.y*PI2 /50.0  * sin(t) )), roadWidth, roadSmoothing) /1. ; // road strip
    
        vec3 c = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, base, l);
        // vec3 base2 = vec3(0.1,0.6,0.4) * wave(tuv.x, mix(0.5, 0.36, getDelta(vPos.y*PI2 /50.0  * cos(t) )), 0.06, 0.02) /1. ; // road strip
        // vec3 c2 = mix(c, base2, l);
        
     
        gl_FragColor = vec4(c, diffuseColor.a);
      `,
    )
```

It adds the functionality you provide at the very end of the fragment shader's `main` function.